# PHP не обрабатывает русский язык

Tags: php, gallery

```html
<?php 


include '/classes/image_class.php';

$obj_image = new Image();

if(@$_POST['Submit'])
{
 $obj_image->image_name=str_replace("'", "''", $_POST['txt_image_name']);
 $obj_image->image=str_replace("'", "''", $_POST['txt_image']);

 $obj_image->Insert_into_image();

 $data_image=$obj_image->get_all_image_list();
 $row=mysql_num_rows($data_image);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>NOvaeye </title>
</head>
<body>
 <CENTER><H1>Novaeyewear</H1></CENTER>
 <CENTER><H2>Sunglass</H2></CENTER>

 <CENTER>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <table border="1" width="80%">
    <tr>
     <th width="50%">IMage NAme</th>
     <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="txt_image_name"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th width="50%">Upload IMage</th>
     <td width="50%"><input type="file" name="txt_image"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td width="50%"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></input></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
 </CENTER>

 <?php 
  if($row!=0)
  {
  ?>
  <center>
   <table width="80%" border="1"> 
   <?php
    $icount = 1;
    while($data= mysql_fetch_assoc($data_image))
    {
     ?>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo $icount; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['image_name']?></td>
      <td><img src="/gallery/images/<?php echo $data['image']; ?>" width="400px" height="200px"></td>
     </tr>
     <?php
     $count++;
     }
     ?>
   </table>
  </center>
  <?php
 }

 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
 <?php
 include 'db/db.php' ;

 class Image{

  var 
   $image_id,
   $image_name,
   $image;
  
  function Insert_into_image(){
   if(isset($_FILES['txt_image']))
   {
       $tempname = $_FILES['txt_image']['tmp_name'];
       $originalname =$_FILES['txt_image']['name'];
       $size =($_FILES['txt_image']['size']/5242888). "MB<br>";
       $type=$_FILES['txt_image']['type'];
       $image=$_FILES['txt_image']['name'];
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES['txt_image']['tmp_name'],"images/".$_FILES['txt_image']['name']);
     }
  

   $query = "Insert into t_image_upload
    (
     image_name,
     image
    )
    values
    (
     '$this->image_name',
     '$image'
    )";
    if(mysql_query($query)){
     echo "Insert success";
    }
    else
    {
     echo "Insert not success";
    }
  }

  function get_all_image_list(){
   $query = "select *from t_image_upload";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   return $result;
  }

}
?>
```

[image: Пишем запрос]
[image: Не обрабатывает русский язык]

## Фишка в чем

Вот у меня система загрузки картинок на сервер(ГАЛЕРЕЯ).
И к загружаемой картинке  можно дописать заголовок.
В данном случае у меня написано "#ПРИМЕР" и когда я отправляю запрос, то он его забивает в базу, но в самой базе (PhpMyAdmin) видно то что он записал "#" тобишь русский язык так сказать не видит, а английский без проблем. В чем беда?

Comment: Попробуйте распечатать `var_dump($query);` и посмотреть, все ли с ним нормально. Это даст понять, с базой проблема или где-то раньше

Comment: Нет, Я из Латвии)

Comment: Попробуйте через phpMyAdmin добавить значение с кириллицей. Возможно, кодировка вашей БД не поддерживает кириллицу

Comment: Да, вы были правы. Все из-за кодировки) Paldies!